# JAVA how to check array parameter

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 classes. one is named "shipment", the other is called "Inventory"
inside the shipment, there are some variables as below.

```
public class Shipment
{
private int trackingCode;
private int priority;
private double shippingPrice;
private double weight;
private String originCity;
private String destCity;
private String trackingPage;
```

and I create the "Inventory" as below

```
public class Inventory
{

private ArrayList<Shipment> packages;

public Inventory(Shipment[] listOfPackage)
{
    if(listOfPackage == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("List of Packages cannot be null.");
    }

    packages = new ArrayList<Shipment>(Arrays.asList(listOfPackage));  

}
```

Now my question is how do I create a method to add a new package to the ArrayList, and also duplicate tracking code is not allowed need to throw an exception.

```
public ArrayList<Package> addPackage()
```

I'm very confusing how to do the duplicate tracking code check because it's one of the Shipment[] array element

Comment: Is `Package` and `Shipment` the same thing? If not do specify what Package is.

Comment: Yes. the Inventory access the shipment, so I write the constructor and set an array parameter that invokes all the variables from the Shipment.

Comment: Your code and naming conventions are very confusing. You are missing closing curly braces `}` in your post, so it is difficult to know where one class begins and the other one ends.

Also this is not a valid function: `public Warehouse(Shipment[] listOfPackage)`

Did you mean: `public Warehouse warehouseFromShipments(Shipment[] listOfShipments)` ?

The fact that you call 'shipments' 'packages' is also confusing. Why not just stick to one naming convention?

Comment: Sorry I corrected the code above.  the second one is "Inventory" class and it has one variable named  private ArrayList<Shipment> packages;  and the constructor is the following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword to refer to your private member variables and still keep a similar naming convention for parameters passed into your constructor or functions. It makes your code much more understandable to others and to yourself =). Having two separate naming conventions for everything you pass into a class can get very confusing.

I have added a main function to demonstrate how you would effectively operate on these classes.

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // define some unique shipments
        Shipment a = new Shipment(1,1, 10.0, 20.3, "Denver", "Seattle", "xyz");
        Shipment b = new Shipment(2,9, 45.88, 130.1, "Denver", "Los Angeles", "xyz");
        Shipment c = new Shipment(3,3, 14.67, 6.8, "Houston", "Dallas", "xyz");
        Shipment d = new Shipment(1,4, 12.99, 2.3, "New York", "London", "xyz");

        // populate your inventory with an array of initial shipments "a", "b", and "c"
        Shipment[] initialShipments = new Shipment[] { a, b, c };
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory(initialShipments);

        // print the inventory before adding the new shipment
        System.out.println(inventory.toString());

        // add shipment "d" to your inventory with the new method
        try {
            inventory.addShipment(d);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        // print the inventory after adding the new shipment
        System.out.println(inventory.toString());
    }

}
```

For your `Inventory`:

```
public class Inventory {

    private ArrayList<Shipment> shipments;

    public Inventory(Shipment[] shipments) {
        if(shipments == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("List of shipments cannot be null.");
        }
        this.shipments = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(shipments));
    }

    public void addShipment(Shipment shipment) throws Exception {

        Optional<Shipment> duplicateShipment = shipments
                .stream()
                .filter(otherShipment -> otherShipment.getTrackingCode() == shipment.getTrackingCode())
                .findAny();

        if(duplicateShipment.isPresent()) {
            String errorMessage = MessageFormat.format(
                    "A shipment with tracking code {0} already exists in this inventory.",
                    shipment.getTrackingCode()
            );
            throw new Exception(errorMessage);
        }
        else {
            this.shipments.add(shipment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Inventory{" +
                "shipments=" + shipments +
                '}';
    }
}
```

In order to check for duplicate tracking codes, you must make a stream of your existing shipments so that you can look for any tracking code in those shipments that match the one you are trying to add.

There are many ways to accomplish this in theory, but I did it by making a stream of your shipments so I could make a `filter` that looked for any shipment tracking code equal to the one you are adding.

The `findAny` at the end of this stream just returns an `Optional` which means that it could potentially return something or not.

With the `Optional` type, you can test if it found a duplicate by using the `isPresent()` function. If the duplicate is present, you can throw an exception, as needed.

Here I just made the function throw up the Exception, but you could handle it here in the function and just log that you tried to add the same shipment. In real code, you wouldn't want your code to break because you tried to add a duplicate shipment. You would just want to stop it from happening and move on!

For your `Shipment`:

```
public class Shipment {
    private int trackingCode;
    private int priority;
    private double shippingPrice;
    private double weight;
    private String originCity;
    private String destCity;
    private String trackingPage;

    public Shipment(int trackingCode, int priority, double shippingPrice, double weight, String originCity, String destCity, String trackingPage) {
        this.trackingCode = trackingCode;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.shippingPrice = shippingPrice;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.originCity = originCity;
        this.destCity = destCity;
        this.trackingPage = trackingPage;
    }

    public int getTrackingCode() {
        return trackingCode;
    }
}
```

You need to add a 'getter' to the `Shipment` class so that you can access the tracking code outside of this class; otherwise, it will remain private, and you won't be able to make comparisons outside of this class where you need to check for duplicate tracking codes.

Comment: Thank you so much, you explained very clearly. As a java beginner that really helps me.

Comment: I also don't think I answered your question completely... Sorry about that. I thought about your question some more and fixed my answer.

Comment: @Dunky I've added some comments around the new edits. Let me know if this answers your original questions.

Comment: Yes. it did answer my question. I really appreciate your help. You're awesome.

Comment: @Dunky don't forget to mark my answer with the check mark on the side if it is the best solution for you.